# Programmatically hide (but not quit) application on OS X

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-8

On OS X, is there a possibility (JDK8u40) to programmatically hide the application, similar to what is typically achieved by a user who presses Cmd-H?

I have, unsuccessfully, tried:

- calling Stage.setIconified
- calling Stage.hide() with the Platform.setImplicitExit option previously set to true (=> the application remains active, although the stage disappears)
- calling Stage.hide() without the Platform.setImplicitExit option (=> the application is quit)
- using AWT Robot to send the Cmd-H shortcut (produces the About box instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that on OS X for example by using the Cocoa native bindings of Eclipse SWT. That might not be the most elegant solution but it should work though. If you include the following dependency to your project (make sure to disable -XstartOnFirstThread in your run configuration)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.4.3.swt</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
  <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

you can call

```
OS.objc_msgSend(NSApplication.sharedApplication().id,
                    OS.sel_hide_);
```

This will call the exact same procedure as triggered by CMD-h and will thus work on OS X only, of course.